# How can I create a console application that utlilitize async/await

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I'm creating a weather app that polls temperature from a service I've made:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Weather
{
    class Program
    {
        static BackgroundWorker bgw;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            bgw = new BackgroundWorker();
            bgw.DoWork += bgw_DoWork;
            bgw.RunWorkerAsync();
        }

        static async void bgw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            Weather bot = new Weather();

            if (bot.IsRunning)
            {
                await bot.Update();
            }
        }
    }

    public class Weather
    {
        public bool IsRunning { get; set; }

        private DateTime lastUpdated;

        public Weather()
        {
            IsRunning = true;

            lastUpdated = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
        }

        public async Task<bool> Update()
        {
            if (lastUpdated < DateTime.Now)
            {
                lastUpdated = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(30);

                // temperature
                double value = await GetLatestValue("New York");
            }

            return true;
        }

        private async Task<double> GetLatestValue(string city)
        {
            string url = "http://www" + city;

            var client = new WebClient();
            string data = await client.DownloadStringTaskAsync(url);

            return 4.3;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem here is that it does not seem to work? The GetLatesValue function is just jibberish, will just return 4.3 for testing purposes.

What happens is that on `await GetLatestValue` the console application just quits.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is simpler than you might think: you are running a `BackgroundWorker`, which basically wraps a thread that has `.IsBackground = true`. Such threads will not keep a process alive - they will be shut down automatically when the process exits. The process will exit when all *non*-background threads are completed.

Your `Main` method starts the `BackgroundWorker`, but then does nothing else - `Main` exits, and the application is complete. The `BackgroundWorker` is then shut down at whatever point it's reached. There's nothing wrong with the code it's running - but the app is shutting down without letting it complete.

**EDIT:** if you want to test this, simply put a `Console.ReadLine()` at the end of your `Main` - it'll keep the application alive until you press Enter, and so you should see your thread run until you do.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to [Dan Puzey's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23778000/1768303), there's not much sense in assigning an `async void` method as an event handler for `BackgroundWorker`, in the first place.

Your worker method `bgw_DoWork` will return and the background thread will be finished as soon as the execution point hits the first `await` inside `bgw_DoWork`. The `bot.Update` task most likely still will be pending at that point.

You don't need a `BackgroundWorker` here. The code can be as simple as this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    DoWorkAsync().Wait();
}

static async Task DoWorkAsync()
{
    Weather bot = new Weather();

    if (bot.IsRunning)
    {
        await bot.Update();
    }
}
```